# Copying file didn't working

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, file-copying

I'm trying copy file to startup folder. Here is my code:

```
            String ^path;
            path = Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::CommonStartup);
            path += "\\EFM.lnk";

            if(!IO::File::Exists(path))
                IO::File::Copy("C:\\lng\\EFM.lnk",path);
```

It's simple but don't working. I would like to ask you: "why"?

Comment: *How* is it not working? Is it throwing an exception? Is there no exception, but the destination file isn't created?

Comment: @DavidYaw No exception and no destination file. Variable `path` and `if()` is ok and working. Only `File::Copy` method didn't working.

Comment: Does your process have administrative rights? If it doesn't, have you checked that the folder may have been redirected to `C:\Users\{your name}\AppData\Local\VirtualStore` ? (By the way, you should use Path::Combine() rather than append and bother with inserting backslashes by hand)

Comment: @Medinoc: you're right, administrative rights it was problem, now it's working. Thanks. (PS. Thanks for tip with Path::Combine(), I will remember this).

Comment: I'm transfering this to answers so it doesn't look like an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process lacks administrative rights and its manifest doesn't mark it as aware of UAC isolation, writes to the Common Startup folder (which requires administator access) may be silently redirected to `C:\Users\{your name}\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.

This explains both the lack of file in the real folder and the lack of `UnauthorizedAccessException` or any other error.